# getting hostname of remote computers on the local network not setup in /etc/hosts

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, hostname

I have a new learning, I was trying to get hostname using python's socket.

so from my macbook I ran the below code:

```
socket.gethostbyaddr("192.168.1.111")
```

and I get the `('rock64', [], ['192.168.1.111'])` then I tried IP address of a computer that is not on the network anymore but used to be:

```
socket.gethostbyaddr("192.168.1.189")
```

and it returned: `('mint', [], ['192.168.1.189'])` then I realised its coming from the `/etc/hosts` file.

now in that host file I also have this entry:

**/etc/hosts**

`172.217.25.3 google.com.hk`

but if I try to get host from ip of wan address i get different results than expected!

socket.gethostbyaddr("172.217.25.3")

that returns `('hkg07s24-in-f3.1e100.net', ['3.25.217.172.in-addr.arpa'], ['172.217.25.3'])`

so I am not wondering where in the later case of WAN ip address I am getting the hostname and why in case of local computer IP's I am getting hostname from the configured /etc/hosts file ?

How can we get hostname of host computers on the local network without `socket.gethostbyaddr` having to look into **/etc/hosts** file or by other means ?

Comment: what host name do you expect to get and what for? reverse DNS lookup is usually useful when combating spammers , i.e. in cases when server owners have incentive to register proper domain name with RIPE. Majority of IP addresses do not resolve back to anything meaningful so I wonder what would be the reason for doing it.

Comment: I am mostly interested in getting the name of hosts on local network ! But i only get host name for the one i have set up in /etc/hosts file

Comment: there is no such term as "hostname" at layers 2 and 3 of OSI model. DNS, MDNS, NETBIOS are layer 5,7 application protocols. You can use them to get leaked names but it could be unreliable because host on your network may not run any services which could be used for service discovery. So my question is : what kind of host names do you need and for what purpose?

Comment: the one that we get when we do `echo $HOSTNAME` or the one that router says host id under dhcp settings

Comment: $HOSTNAME is internal private thing which has nothing to do with outside world unless host wants to share such info with neighbours via avahi-daemon or something similar. Router gets leaked hostnames in some specific cases via dhcp requests. You can monitor your network for such leaks(netbios, mdns, dhcp, etc) but such information would be irrelevant for communication purposes. you can sniff for such leaks to build MAC=>name association map to assist some logging in IDS system. Could you please tell us *agian* what is your purpose for getting "host names" of local network hosts?

Comment: I want to build a registry of computers on the network along with mac and ip address.

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based answer to the question "how to build registry of network devices on your local network?"

The best way to build registry of devices on your local network is to setup `ntopng` on your gateway. It uses DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) Technics to collect information about hosts.
NTOPNG has nice user interface and displays host names (when possible).
You can assign aliases for specific hosts which do not leak host names via any protocol.

For some reasons ntopng developers did not include alias into json response for request http://YOUR-SERVER:3000/lua/host_get_json.lua?ifid=2&host=IP-OF-DEVICE .

You can add it manually by adding lines `require "mac_utils"` and `hj["alias"]=getDeviceName(hj["mac_address"])` into file /usr/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_get_json.lua

You can use [REST API](https://www.ntop.org/guides/ntopng/api/) to interrogate ntopng and use provided information for building any script you need.

Comment: I will give this a try. New way of thinking.