# get local hostname from ip adress i.e. 192.168.1.x python 3 on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ip-address, hostname, mac-address

currently using:-
    import socket

```
hostip='192.168.1.62'
getip=socket.getaddrinfo(hostip,port=22)
```

returns info but does not include Hostname.
seems to be a local DNS problem from other discussions.
The local router finds all hostnames.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60280907/12396017

Answer (score 0):

Hostname is only maintained by windows or netbios, so from a command prompt it is virtually impossible to find. So I switched to searching for the ip address by referencing the Mac address. 
The best solution so far is to use nmap and parse the results. 
My code for ip addresses up to 192.268.1.99 is this

```
mac='0a:0b:0c:0d'
arpin=os.popen('nmap -sP -n 192.168.1.0/24',"r").read()
arl=arpin.split("\n")
fmac=[arl.index(i) for i in arl if mac in i]
fip=arl[fmac[0]-2][-12:]
```

fip gets the ip address of the device.